# NSView -dataWithPDFInsideRect: and layer borders

Tags: objective-c, nsview

I'm using `-dataWithPDFInsideRect:` with an `NSView` that has many subviews.  It works fine but doesn't render any of the subview's layer properties like borders.  Is there a way to get that to work?

Comment: Is the border value negative or postive?

Comment: So, maybe it is a clipping problem? Are there other properties definetly not influenced by clipping?

Answer (score 3):

Add:

```
((NSView *)self.window.contentView).wantsLayer = YES;
```

Comment: `NSView` doesn't have this property.

Comment: @BerryBlue I was sure it was UIView, edited my answer accordingly. That is the equivalent of clip to bounds in iOS.

Comment: @BerryBlue did you make sure to add this where you create the NSView? Also, can you share some code?